# How can I hide the to: address when printing from Mail.app

Tags: macos, email, printing, apple-mail

I need to print out emailed receipts for tax purposes, but I would rather not have my email address present in the printout.

Is it possible to change the format that Mail.app uses to print, to just show the name (which is what it does on screen) when it prints?

I am running Snow Leopard, with Mail.app version 4.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do this in Mail, but...

1. Print the email, but open PDF in Preview instead of printing.
2. In Preview: Tools > Annotate > Add Rectangle
3. Drag a rectangle over the text to be removed
4. Select the rectangle and press Cmd-I to bring up the inspector window
5. Click the rightmost Annotations Inspector button and change opacity to 100% and colour to white (or whatever suits)
6. Select File > Print... (do NOT click the Print button at the bottom of the window)

I appreciate this is a bit long winded if you have many emails to print!